# Convert Hierarchical DataTable to Json

Tags: json, linq, datatable, nested-lists, sublist

I have a hierarchial data table as follows which generates menu and its sub menus. main menu has parentId as 0. Submenu has parent Ids referring to parentId.

```html
ResourceId   DisplayName   ParentId     Url
-----------------------------------------------
1           Home           0            Some Url
2           Student        0            Some Url
3           Staff          0            Some Url
4           Library        0            Some Url
6           StudentAtt     1            Some Url
7           TimeTable      1            Some Url
8           Staff Att      2            Some Url
9           Book Issue     3            Some Url
10          Book Return    3            Some Url
11          Fee Payment    4            Some Url
12          Book fine      10           Some Url
```

need to convert it to Json. Below is the code i tried out. I am trying to check if ParentId of SubMenu equals ResourceId of main Menu. But subMenu is not displayed. (variable table is DataTable)

```html
var rows = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
            var result = rows.Where(x => x["ParentId"].ToString() == "0").GroupBy(r => new { x = r["ResourceId"] }).Select(
                g => new
                {
                    //MenuLevel = g.Key.x,
                    MenuDetails = g.GroupBy(r => new {a = r["DisplayName"], b = r["Url"]}).Select(
                        detail => new
                        {
                            DisplayName = detail.Key.a,
                            Url = detail.Key.b,
                            SubMenu =
                                detail.Where(y => g.Key.x.ToString()==y["ParentId"].ToString()).
                                    GroupBy(r => new {f = r["DisplayName"]}).Select(
                                    subMenu=>new
                                    {
                                        SubMenuDisplayName=subMenu.Key.f
                                    }
                                    )
                        }
                        )
                });
```

the result i got is as below.

```
[{"MenuDetails":[{"DisplayName":"Home","Url":null,"SubMenu":[]}]},{"MenuDetails":[{"DisplayName":"Student","Url":null,"SubMenu":[]}]},{"MenuDetails":[{"DisplayName":"Staff","Url":null,"SubMenu":[]}]},{"MenuDetails":[{"DisplayName":"Library","Url":null,"SubMenu":[]}]}]
```

But expected result is:

```
[{"MenuDetails":[{"DisplayName":"Home","Url":null,"SubMenu":[{"SubMenuDisplayName":"StudentAtt"},{"SubMenuDisplayName":"TimeTable"}]}]},{"MenuDetails":[{"DisplayName":"Student","Url":null,"SubMenu":[{"SubMenuDisplayName":"Staff Att"}]}]},{"MenuDetails":[{"DisplayName":"Staff","Url":null,"SubMenu":[{"SubMenuDisplayName":"Book Issue"},{"SubMenuDisplayName":"Book Return"}]}]},{"MenuDetails":[{"DisplayName":"Library","Url":null,"SubMenu":[{"SubMenuDisplayName":"Fee Payment "}]}]}]
```

I also need to display the sub sub menu (which has parent id pointing to resource id of sub menu) Any one please help

Answer (score 0):

The issue your having is in

```
SubMenu = detail.Where(y => ...
```

, detail is already filtered to `rows.Where(x => x["ParentId"].ToString() == "0")` so it does not include the child items.

This would be closer to what you want but only returns the first two levels.

```
var result = rows.Where(x => x["ParentId"].ToString() == "0").GroupBy(r => new { x = r["ResourceId"] }).Select(
    g => new {
        //MenuLevel = g.Key.x,
        MenuDetails = g.GroupBy(r => new { a = r["DisplayName"], b = r["Url"] }).Select(
            detail => new {
                DisplayName = detail.Key.a,
                Url = detail.Key.b,
                SubMenu =
                    rows.Where(y => g.Key.x.ToString() == y["ParentId"].ToString()).
                        GroupBy(r => new { f = r["DisplayName"] }).Select(
                        subMenu => new {
                            SubMenuDisplayName = subMenu.Key.f
                        }
                        )
            }
            )
    });
```

To create the full hierarchy you need to create objects for each menu item then join them together. This is easier if you create a type to represent your menu item, for example:

```
public class MenuDeatils {

    public int ID;
    public string Url;
    public string DisplayName;
    public IEnumerable<MenuDeatils> SubMenu;

}
```

You can then create an object for each item and group them by their ParentIds:

```
var groups = (from row in rows
              group row by row["ParentId"] into parentGroup
              select new {
                Key = (int)parentGroup.Key,
                Items = parentGroup.Select(r => new MenuDeatils {
                    ID = (int)r["ResourceId"],
                    DisplayName = (string)r["DisplayName"],
                    Url = (string)r["Url"]
                })
              }).ToList();
```

Note: The queries are enumerated here (.ToList()) so we create one set of MenuDeatils objects.

Next we can set each MenuDetails object's SubMenu property from the groups we have created.

```
foreach (var menuItem in groups.SelectMany(g => g.Items)) {
    var submenu = groups.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Key == menuItem.ID);
    if (submenu != null) {
        menuItem.SubMenu = submenu.Items;
    }
};
```

The top level items can be found with:

```
var result = groups.Single(g => g.Key == 0).Items
```

, and now have all the descendant menus attached.