# Converting Datatable to sublist using linq - retrieve rows without group by key

Tags: c#, json, linq, datatable, group-by

I need some help in this problem. 
I am trying to convert my datatable to a hierarchial sublist and then to json using LINQ. Below code is working perfect.

```
var result = rows
    .GroupBy(x => new {b = x["Name"], a = x["Id"], c = x["MorningShift"], d = x["EveningShift"]})
    .OrderBy(a => a.Key.b)
    .Select(empl => new
    {
        Id = empl.Key.a,
        Name = empl.Key.b,
        MorningShift = empl.Key.c,
        EveningShift = empl.Key.d,
        Details = empl
            .Select(z => new
            {
                RouteId=z["RouteId"],
                ReportingHRName = z["ReportingHRName"],
                ShiftType = z["ShiftType"]
            })
            .OrderBy(a => a.ReportingHRName)

    });
```

An employee can have morning shift or evening shift or both. I need details of the employee as a sublist. I think my LINQ knowledge is not good enough. I have done group by Name, Id, MorningShift, EveningShift to retrieve these columns using the key.

But doing so, if an employee has morning shift as null, then there  will be separate lists- having null values and having not null values. (as GroupBy is done)
This is not desired.

So finally, I need some help in retrieving the columns-morningshift and eveningshift without using keys.

Note: If I try to do

```
EveningShift = x["EveningShift"],
MorningShift = x["MorningShift"]
```

then I cannot select ReportingHRName and ShiftType of each employee as sublist.

I got a similar post ([Convert Hierarchical DataTable to Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495860/convert-hierarchical-datatable-to-json)). but this could not answer my question.

Edited sample of datatable:

```
 Id   Name   MorningShift    EveningShift  RouteID ReportingHRName ShiftType
 1   abc       9               null         11      alex           full time
 2   def       8               null         12      robin          part time
 3   geh       null            5            13      shek           full time
 4   def       null            6            13      shek           part time
```

Sample of JSON list

```
    [{"Id":"1","Name":"abc","MorningShift":"9","EveningShift":"null","Details"[{"RouteId":"11","ReportingHRName":"alex","ShiftType":"full time"}]},{"Id":"2","Name":"def","MorningShift":"8","EveningShift":"6","Details":[{"RouteId":"12","ReportingHRName":"robin","ShiftType":"part time"}{"RouteId":"13","ReportingHRName":"shek","ShiftType":"full time"}]}{"Id":"3","Name":"geh","MorningShift":"null","EveningShift":"5","Details"[{"RouteId":"13","ReportingHRName":"shek","ShiftType":"full time"}]}]
```

So the MorningShift and EveningShift should be retrieved without groupby employee name(Name). But RouteId,ReportingHRName and ShiftType should be retrieved groupby employee.

If MorningShift and EveningShift are retrieved by key as in above code, there will be separate details for each MorningShift and EveningShift.

Hope you could understand the issue. Thanks for the response.

This is the code I tried with the below answser.

```
 var groupedItems = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
.GroupBy(x => x["Name"])
.OrderBy(x => x["Name"])
.Select(x => new
{
    Name = x["Name"],
    MorningShift = x["MorningShift"]
    EveningShift = x["MorningShift"],
    Details = x.Select(y => new {RouteId=y["RouteId"],ReportingHRName=y["ReportingHRName"],ShiftType=y["ShiftType"]})
});.
```

But this throws me error. Not able to identify Name, MorningShift etc in the code below.

```
    Name = x["Name"],
    MorningShift = x["MorningShift"]
```

Comment: Can you provide simplified sample of your data table and the desired JSON result?

Comment: I don't understand where is hierarchy here... You are grouping on `Id`, which I suppose is unique. So why `Details` is an array? It will be always only one object because of `Id`.

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov: Thank u so much for pointing it out. I have edited the list. sorry for the confusion. :(

Comment: And when you say DataTable do you mean standard [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: yes @AleksandrIvanov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include `Id` of the row in your JSON because it will not allow to do any grouping (it's unique for every row, if you really need that you can have an array with id's). To get the JSON you want, you need to group only on `Name`. I assume that only `MorningShift` and `EveningShift` columns has `AllowDbNull` set to true. If you have it for some other properties too, you always need to first check it with `IsColumnNameNull()` method.

So here is a code that will group your data:

```
var groupedItems = dt.Rows.Cast<YourDataTableType>()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Name = x.Key,
        MorningShift = x.All(y => y.IsMorningShiftNull())
            ? null
            : x.Sum(y => y.IsMorningShiftNull() ? 0 : (int?) y.MorningShift),
        EveningShift = x.All(y => y.IsEveningShiftNull())
            ? null
            : x.Sum(y => y.IsEveningShiftNull() ? 0 : (int?) y.EveningShift),
        Details = x.Select(y => new {y.RouteId, y.ReportingHRName, y.ShiftType})
    });
```

And then you can easily convert it to JSON. I recommend to use [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for that:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupedItems, Formatting.Indented);
```

And the JSON will be:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "abc",
    "MorningShift": 9,
    "EveningShift": null,
    "Details": [
      {
        "RouteId": 11,
        "ReportingHRName": "alex",
        "ShiftType": "full time"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "def",
    "MorningShift": 8,
    "EveningShift": 6,
    "Details": [
      {
        "RouteId": 12,
        "ReportingHRName": "robin",
        "ShiftType": "part time"
      },
      {
        "RouteId": 13,
        "ReportingHRName": "shek",
        "ShiftType": "part time"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "geh",
    "MorningShift": null,
    "EveningShift": 5,
    "Details": [
      {
        "RouteId": 13,
        "ReportingHRName": "shek",
        "ShiftType": "full time"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**EDIT:** If your DataTable is not typed and you want to access fields by index, the your code might look like that:

```
var groupedItems = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Name"))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Name = x.Key,
        MorningShift = x.All(y => y.IsNull("MorningShift"))
            ? null
            : x.Sum(y => y.Field<int?>("MorningShift")),
        EveningShift = x.All(y => y.IsNull("EveningShift"))
            ? null
            : x.Sum(y => y.Field<int?>("EveningShift")),
        Details = x.Select(y => new
        {
            RouteId = y.Field<int>("RouteId"),
            ReportingHRName = y.Field<string>("ReportingHRName"),
            ShiftType = y.Field<string>("ShiftType")
        })
    });
```

Of course if you have some other data type for some fields (decimal instead of int for example), you should change it.

PS: I also made a small fix in LINQ in my original example. It wasn't correct.

Comment: i think i got it. I will try this n get back to u. once again thanks :)

Comment: It's your first question, so just in case... If answer solved your problem you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: i could not solve it with your code. I am not able to do      .GroupBy(x => x.Name). x["Name"] is also not identified. Not sure if I am going wrong somewhere.

Comment: I am not able to select MorningShift, EveningShift  as a sublist.

Comment: I am getting the following error in x.Sum(y => y.Field<string>("MorningShift"))                                                                                   An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Based on your JSON `MorningShift` is a numeric field. You are trying to cast it to `string`. You should use `int` or `decimal` depending on number type.